# LINQ error invalid initializer member declarator

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I'm a fairly junior C# developer so excuse me if this is trivial, but I am coming up with this error "invalid initializer member declarator" at the line of code I indicate below.

Can someone explain what this means and how do I work around/achieve this result? All of my data annotations are already applied once in PODetail, which is why I didn't want to repeat the properties here as well.

```
public class PODetailsListViewModel : IViewModelList<PODetail, PODetailsListViewModel>, IEntity
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string EntityDescription
        {
            get
            { return this.Id.ToString(); }
        }

        public PODetail PODetail { get; set; }


        public IEnumerable<PODetailsListViewModel> ConvertClassToViewModel(IEnumerable<PODetail> poDetails)
        {
            IEnumerable<PODetailsListViewModel> contactGrid =
                from l in poDetails.ToList()
                select new PODetailsListViewModel()
                {
                    Id = l.Id,
                    PODetail.POHeaderId = l.POHeaderId, <===== ERROR on this Line
                    ....
                };

            return contactGrid;
        }
```

Comment: Instinctively I'd have thought you'd need a create an instance of `PODetail`, such as `PODetail = new PODetail { POHeaderId = l.POHeaderID },` .

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't access complex object properties in a class initializer like that (as you are attempting with the `PODetail.POHeaderId` property). You might have to implement a small workaround: create a collection of anonymous objects with the information you have already, then reconstruct a concrete list of `PODetailsListViewModel`s right afterwards:

```
var contactGrid = from l in poDetails.ToList()
                  select new {
                  {
                       Id = l.Id,
                       POHeaderId = l.POHeaderId
                       ...
                  };
```

And then you can manually recreate what you're looking for:

```
var someNewCollection = New List(Of PODetailsListViewModel);
foreach (var item in contactGrid)
    var model = new PODetailsListViewModel()
    {
         Id = item.Id
    };
    model.PODetail = new PODetailModel() /* replace with actual class name */
    {
        POHeaderId = item.POHeaderId
    };
    someNewCollection.Add(model);
}
return someNewCollection;
```

**EDIT**: Or perhaps you could nest the initializers:

```
var contactGrid = from l in poDetails.ToList()
                  select new PODetailsListViewModel() {
                  {
                       Id = l.Id,
                       PODetail = new PODetailModel()
                       {
                           POHeaderId = l.POHeaderId
                       },
                       ...
                  };
```

Comment: Cory, thanks for the great detail. The nesting worked perfect....until I got to trying to use that view model in my Kendo UI grid....then again I got null reference errors. For now I have given up and just reverted back to duplicating my properties int the view model. That said, this is the answer to my question.

Comment: Nice example Helped me to figure out my problem