# Invalid Initializer Member Declarator

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I am trying to check if a field returned from SQL is null or not but I keep getting "Invalid Initializer Member Declarator" on the isDBNull

Here is my code, what could be causing this?

```
while (dr.Read())
{
    staff.Add(new Staff()
    {
        id = dr.GetInt32(dr.GetOrdinal("id")),
        dr.IsDBNull(dr.GetOrdinal("NAME")) ? null : dr.GetString(dr.GetOrdinal("NAME")),

        PARENT = dr.GetString(dr.GetOrdinal("PARENT")),
        VALUE = dr.GetString(dr.GetOrdinal("VALUE")),
        VALUETYPE = dr.GetString(dr.GetOrdinal("VALUETYPE"))
    });
}
```

Comment: Please view this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14405553/linq-error-invalid-initializer-member-declarator

Comment: Did you mean `Name = dr.IsDBNull(...`

Answer (score 5):

Make sure all properties are initialized within `{}`
e.g.

```C#
PropertyName = dr.IsDBNull(dr.GetOrdinal("NAME")) ? null : dr.GetString(dr.GetOrdinal("NAME")),
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure you can execute conditional statement while initializing a member variable. You are actually trying to call the constructor, which initializes the member variable.

May be the easiest approach is to create the object explicitly and then add it to the collection.

```
Staff staff= new Staff();
```

Assign the values to the **object**, where you can check for the `NULL` values and then assign the properties. Otherwise pass the value to the constructor as `dr["Name"]` and handle the check within the constructor.

Hope this helps.