# Converting double to float C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, datagrid

I need to display information in a datagrid from my **tblSysproStock** table. The table has columns with float values in them and in my application I need to convert the **double** value to a **float** value

My coding where I want to fill my datagrid:

```
private void FillSysproDataGrid()
{
    using (DataClassesDataContext DC = new DataClassesDataContext())
    {
        dgSysproStock.ItemsSource = DC.tblSysproStocks.Where<tblSysproStock>(c => c.StockID != null)
            .Select<tblSysproStock, SSData>(m => new SSData()
            {
                SID = m.StockID,
                SCode = m.StockCode,
                SDescription = m.StockDescription,
                SConvFactAltUom = (float)m.ConvFactAltUom,
                SConvMulDiv = m.ConvMulDiv,
                SConvFactOthUom = (float)m.ConvFactOthUom,
                SMulDiv = m.MulDiv,
                SMass = (float)m.Mass,
                SUpdatedSupplier = m.UpdatedSupplier,
                SCycleCount = (float)m.CycleCount,
                SProductClass = (float)m.ProductClass,
                SUnitCost = (float)m.UnitCost,
                SSegal = m.Segal,
                SWareHouse = m.Warehouse,
                SMinimumStock = (float)m.MinimumStock,
                SMaximumStock = (float)m.MaximumStock,
                SStockForNow = (float)m.StockForNow,
                SStockCount = m.StockCount,
                SValue = (float)m.Value,
            });
    }
}
```

I am equaling my values from my table to my SSData class:

```
public struct SSData
{
    public string _ss;

    public int SID { get; set; }
    public string SCode { get; set; }
    public string SDescription { get; set; }
    public float SConvFactAltUom { get; set; }
    public string SConvMulDiv { get; set; }
    public float SConvFactOthUom { get; set; }
    public string SMulDiv { get; set; }
    public float SMass { get; set; }
    public string SUpdatedSupplier { get; set; }
    public float SCycleCount { get; set; }
    public float SProductClass { get; set; }
    public float SUnitCost { get; set; }
    public string SSegal { get; set; }
    public string SWareHouse { get; set; }
    public float SMinimumStock { get; set; }
    public float SMaximumStock { get; set; }
    public float SStockForNow { get; set; }
    public string SStockCount { get; set; }
    public float SValue { get; set; }
}
```

Now the error that I am getting is -

> *The null value cannot be assigned to a member with type System.Single which is a non-nullable value type.* When I run my application.

I think that it's the conversion that is the problem? Anyone with any advice or solutions would be great! Thank you.

EDIT: @Greg, ok so I used the new coding and here is a snippet:

```
    using (DataClassesDataContext DC = new DataClassesDataContext())
    {
        dgSysproStock.ItemsSource = DC.tblSysproStocks.Where<tblSysproStock>(c => c.StockID != null)
            .Select<tblSysproStock, SSData>(m => new SSData()
            {
                SID = m.StockID,
                SCode = m.StockCode,
                SDescription = m.StockDescription,
                float.TryParse(m.ConvFactAltUom, out SConvFactAltUom),
            });
    }
```

lol, and the error I get is -

> Invalid initializer member declarator

I am very new to coding and I think that I might be using the coding you gave the wrong way?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
 float.TryParse(m.ConvFactAltUom, out SConvFactAltUom);
```

just to make sure it works. It will convert the value to float if possible or leave the property untouched and won't throw an exception.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the reply. The coding that you gave, gives me this error: "The as operator must be used with a reference type or nullable type ('float' is a  non-nullable value type)".

Comment: Edited in a missing "?"

Comment: It's still giving me errors with the added "?" :(. 'Cannot convert type 'double?' to 'float?' via a reference conversion, boxing conversion, unboxing conversion, wrapping conversion or null type conversion'.

Comment: @CareTaker22 sorry it was my mistake you can use ?? just with objects, see edited answer.

Comment: @Greg I used the coding, but can you please see the EDIT I made in the original question, thank you.

Comment: @CareTaker22 this is because the way you create your complex object(SSData). There are plenty post on SO explained how to make it right, check out this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14405553/linq-error-invalid-initializer-member-declarator?answertab=active#tab-top